# Filter [Node] to [Element] with ghcjs-dom

Tags: haskell, dom, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

I am using ghcjs-dom. How can I filter the elements out of an array of nodes?

```
import GHCJS.DOM.Types

nodesToElements :: [Node] -> [Element]
nodesToElements = ??
```

or

```
nodesToElements :: [Node] -> IO [Element]
nodesToElements = ??
```

Comment: Where are these types documented?

Comment: @dfeuer there is no documentation that I can find. I found some examples by googling "ghcjs-dom".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import GHCJS.DOM.Types
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

nodeToElement :: Node -> Maybe Element
nodeToElement node = if node `isA` gTypeElement
                     then Just $ castToElement node
                     else Nothing

nodesToElements :: [Node] -> [Element]
nodesToElements = mapMaybe nodeToElement
```